# Assembly program for choosing file from command line and write it

Tags: assembly

I have troubles with assembly code. 
I need to write programm which:
a) will get filename from command line and open it
b) will write file contents in command line
Here is my code:

```
section .date
  file_name db 128
  point_fname dd file_name
  string db 80
         len_string = $ - string
  point_string dd string
  handle dw 0
  size_f dd 0

section .text

global _start
_start:
main:
  mov di, 81h
  mov al, " "
  mov cx, 128
  repe scasb
  dec di
  push di
  pop si
  mov ax, @data
  mov es, ax
  mov cl, ds:[80h]
  dec cl
  lea di, file_name
  rep movsb
  push es
  pop ds

  mov al, 00h
  lds dx, point_fname
  mov ah, 3dh
  int 21h
  js exit
  mov handle, ax

  mov bx, ax
  mov al, 2
  xor cx, cx
  xor dx, dx
  mov ah, 42h
  int 21h
  jc exit

  shl eax, 16
  shld edx, eax, 16
  mov size_f, edx

  mov bx, handle
  mov al, 0
  xor cx, cx
  xor dx, dx
  mov ah, 42h
  int 21h
  jc exit
```

After compile, I see this mistake:

```
asm:5: error: parser: instruction expected.
```

I have no ideas what should I do. Help, please

Comment: Ask the original programmer who wrote it, which assembler should be used to compile it. Then read it's documentation to be sure you know what that line 5 does in the target assembler. Then read documentation of your assembler, how to write something equivalent, or at least similar + fix code as needed (if I would take a wild guess, you are trying to assemble FASM source with NASM, which generally doesn't need that much fixing to make it work, but some fixing is needed, as you found out).

Comment: What assembler do you use? What architecture and operating system is this?

Comment: `len_string equ $ - string` ?

Comment: or simple remove this line, len_string isn't used anyways

Comment: I'm going to gather from this code that is a mixture of NASM and MASM/TASM code that you pieced together code from a variety of internet tutorials online to come up with this?

Comment: It is clear from the error you are assembling with NASM. But this line `mov ax, @data` is MASM/TASM syntax. Line 5 also used MASM/TASM syntax that NASM doesn't understand. Ifusing NASM you can only create COM programs so they also need an `ORG 0x100` directive etc.